# Can't see the ID of the hotel table in adminjs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, adminjs

I have 2 fields which are named hotel and hotel description. In admin page when I add the hotel ID to hotel description [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VT7VH.jpg). But in the hotel description table on the admin page, the id is not visible [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoCw5.jpg).

Here is typeorm entities for them.
Hotel.entity

```
@Entity()
export class Hotel extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
    id: string;

    @Column({ unique: true, nullable: true })
    hotelName: string;

    @OneToMany(
        () => HotelDescription,
        (hotelDescription) => hotelDescription.hotel,
    )
    hotelDescriptions: HotelDescription[];

    @OneToMany(() => Reservation, (reservation) => reservation.hotel)
    reservations: Reservation[];
}
```

HotelDescription.entity

```
@Entity()
export class HotelDescription extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
    id: string;

    @Column({ type: "text", enum: Language, nullable: true })
    language: Language;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @Column()
    description: string;

    @OneToOne(() => Service, (service) => service.hotelDescription)
    services: Service;

    @OneToMany(() => Treatment, (treatment) => treatment.hotelDescription)
    treatments: Treatment[];

    @ManyToOne(() => Hotel, (hotel) => hotel.hotelDescriptions)
    hotel: Hotel;
}
```

I tried to @JoinColumn to try to add hotelId to the entity but that failed (removed in the code above)